# Why do I get ConnectionRefused error when I change a redis host from an ipv4 host to an ipv6 host?

Tags: python-3.x, redis

```
(Earth) src $ redis --version
Redis server v=6.2.6 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=6624c1a22d50ac4f
(Earth) src $ pip freeze | grep redis
aioredis==1.3.1
channels-redis==4.1.0
hiredis==2.0.0
redis==4.6.0
```

redis.conf:

```
daemonize yes
bind ip6-localhost
port 6380
requirepass protect
timeout 0
...
```

The error:

```
$ django shell
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 24 2022, 14:42:51) [GCC 9.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import redis

In [2]: client = redis.Redis('ip6-localhost', 6380, decode_responses=True, password='protect')

In [3]: client.ping()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

If I start redis normally, I see the process running and claiming to use the ipv6 only host (ip6-localhost) but the python redis client raises a ConnectionRefused error. The only change from its perspective is the switch from localhost to ip6-localhost.

I can use the redis-cli with the same parameters (from redis.conf) to connect and view keys etc. so this looks like it is a problem with pyredis. I tried upgrading it to 5.0.1 (the latest) but this made no difference.